# RecursionError at /person/ maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__

Tags: python, django

My inclusion tag gives "RecursionError at /person/

maximum recursion depth exceeded in **instancecheck**" error.

Full traceback:
Template error:
In template /home/ohid/test_venv/alumni/member/templates/member/person_list.html, error at line 15

my person_list.html:

```
{% extends 'alumni/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Members</h2>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>sl.</th>
            <th>Name and Position</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Organisation & Address</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
        </tr>
        {% for person in persons %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}.</td>
            <td>{{person.name}}<br>
            {{person.present_position}}
</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'member:person-list' %}">
            <img src="{{ person.photo_url|default_if_none:'#'}}" class="img-responsive">
        </a></td>
            <td>
            {{person.organization}}<br>
           {{person.address}}
            </td>
            <td>
             {{person.tele_land}}<br>
             {{person.tele_cell}}<br>
             {{person.email}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

my inclusion tag:

```
from django import template
from ..models import Person

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('member/person_list.html')
def get_person_list():
    return {'persons': Person.objects.all()}
```

my person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    present_position=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organization= models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    tele_land = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    tele_cell = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    photo= ResizedImageField(size=[60, 60],crop=['middle', 'center'],upload_to='persons/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=True,
        help_text="Person Picture")    
    category = models.ForeignKey('Membership', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member_since = models.DateField(blank=True)
    image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default="100")
    image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default="100")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('member:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

my urls:

```
app_name = 'member'
urlpatterns = [
    # Member
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'member/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='member-add'),
    url(r'^person/$', views.PersonListView.as_view(), name='person-list'),
]
```

How to avoid maximum recursion depth? Could anyone suggests the ways?

Edit:
ListView:

```
class PersonListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Person
    context_object_name = 'persons'
```

My base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load member_template_tags %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}">

      <title>Alumnai - {% block title %}Applied Chemistry & Chemical Engineering{% endblock %}</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
       <div id="navbar">
        <nav class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-left">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Search</a>


        </nav>
      </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            {% block sidebar_block %}
                {% get_person_list %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 main">
         {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your PersonList view.

Comment: class PersonListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Person
    context_object_name = 'persons'

please see my update to proper format of my listView.

Comment: There's something missing here. Where are you using that inclusion tag?

Comment: In the base template

Comment: You forgot to post the *full traceback*

Comment: Full traceback is so long nearly 890 lines, therefore I didn't post it

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I posted my base.html in the question, You can see it in my last part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing something very odd here and I can't work out why. You say your base template is using that `get_person_list` inclusion tag, which renders the person_list template. But that's the template for your view; so when you go to /register/, Django goes to the view, starts rendering the person_list template, sees that it extends the base template, starts rendering that, encounters the template tag, starts rendering that template, goes to the base template... As you can see, that's an infinite recursion.

There should be no reason to put such a template tag in the base template in the first place, but even if you do, an inclusion tag should always render its own template, not reuse an existing one from a view.

Comment: Yep, I got your point and made separate templates for inclusion tag. Now its rendering but css not working.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the errors, its working.